# Parallelizing ADX ingestion from query for load balancing

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a function that returns very high volume of data. I am loading the output of the function into a target table. So this is how it goes:-

```
.append async MyTable with(tags=...) <| MyFunction(..arguments..)
```

Because of the very high volume , I would like to fire multiple instance of the query (function basically) and load into the same target table -- I know some column which is a good candidate for uniform distribution of data. Lets call it dept no , which I can pass to the function or filter on top of the function. So this is something I am trying to do :-

```
.append async MyTable with(tags=...) <| MyFunction(..arguments..) | where deptno == 11
.append async MyTable with(tags=...) <| MyFunction(..arguments..) | where deptno == 12
.
.
and so on
```

So lets say if I have 10 of these dept numbers, I will want to fire up 10 different ingestions from 10 different queries.

My question is , is there a way to automatically do it in ADX instead of firing 10 different control commands manually?

I read about partition operator which seems to be doing something logically similar but I am not sure if it runs entire thing as part of a single query or actually creates multiple queries with their own OperationId -- because if it's a single query , if some branch fails , entire operation will fail and nothing will get loaded to the target table , wasting even those query branches which have succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently expected that the caller orchestrates the sequence of commands - that can be done by writing a simple script/app using the client API.

Alternatively - you can submit a feature request for this kind of orchestration to be done by the service, while the caller only runs a single command (-> https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice)